# Is it possible to double your proficiency bonus twice?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, proficiency, stacking

Let's say I'm a multiclass rogue/ranger and I have taken Expertise in survival checks. Now, if a ranger is in their favored terrain it says they double their proficiency bonus in intelligence and wisdom checks relating to you environment. If I am in my favored terrain and use my already doubled survival check, will it double again?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**No**. Per Basic Rules p7 and PHB p12:

> Occasionally,
>   your proficiency bonus might be modified (doubled or
>   halved, for example) before you apply it. If a circumstance
>   suggests that your proficiency bonus applies more than
>   once to the same roll or that it should be multiplied more
>   than once, you nevertheless add it only once, multiply it
>   only once, and halve it only once.